# mac intellij idea tomcat could not show tomcat homepage

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, intellij-idea

I use Mac, intellij idea and tomcat to build a web project. 
when i start tomcat in macOS terminal or intellij idea, it's both success to start tomcat, but when i input "http://localhost:8080" into browser, it can not show tomcat's homepage;
but after i restart Mac book, once again start tomcat , and then input "http://localhost:8080" into browser, it can show tomcat homepage. does someone account this problem? please help, ths very much.

Answer (score 0):

The web project you deployed is in this folder: ${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system/tomcat.

Each web project has it's own configuration file, when you start your ‘RUN CONFIGURATION’ in IDEA, you just start up the specific project.

And it's no matter Mac or windows.

Comment: i cannot find "${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system/tomcat" on my Mac. i did not  understand your thinking, can you explain it in detail? thank you so much. i am a newbiee.

Comment: /Users/${username}/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea${version}/tomcat/